# How to get/create a TlsCredentialedSigner using BouncyCastle?

Tags: security, kotlin, certificate, bouncycastle

I'm trying to implement a DTLS v1.2 handshake using BouncyCastle.  To do so, I need to extend `DefaultTlsServer` and implement `getECDSASignerCredentials` (as I'm using ECDSA), but I'm unsure how to get the `TlsCredentialedSigner` I need to return.  I'm creating an ECDSA-signed certificate like so (after install BouncyCastlePRovider):

```
private fun generateCertificate(
    subject: X500Name,
    keyPair: KeyPair
): Certificate {
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val startDate = Date(now - Duration.ofDays(1).toMillis())
    val expiryDate = Date(now + Duration.ofDays(7).toMillis())
    val serialNumber = BigInteger.valueOf(now)

    val certBuilder = JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(subject, serialNumber, startDate, expiryDate, subject, keyPair.public)
    val signer = JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withECDSA").build(keyPair.private)

    return certBuilder.build(signer).toASN1Structure()
}
```

Should I just create a new `BcDefaultTlsCredentialedSigner`?  Some issues with that:

1. I'd be using BC directly...shouldn't I be able to use only the JCA classes and have BC's provider kick in where needed?
2. `BcDefaultTlsCredentialedSigner` requires the private key in the form of `AsymmetricKeyParameter`, but the way I generated the keys all I have is a `PrivateKey` instance.  Can one be derived from the other? What is the relationship between `AsymmetricKeyParameter` and `PrivateKey`?
3. `BcDefaultTlsCredentialedSigner` requires a `BcTlsCrypto` instance.  Again, I'm not sure whether I should instantiate one of these directly or if I should be able to acquire via JCA using BC as a provider somehow?

And, even more broadly:

1. Is this the idiomatic way to generate a cert using a provider?  I've seen so many different ways to generate certs, some using BC directly, some using JCA with BC as a provider, and some which seem to do a mixture of the two.  What's the proper way?